# $\int x^n(x+a)^{-1} dx$

Tags: integration

I'm looking for an indefinite integral that isn't

$$ \int \frac{x^n}{x+a} dx = \frac{x^{n+1}}{a(n+1)}\,_2F_1(1, n+1; n+2; -x/a),$$

because that doesn't give me finite values when $-x/a > 1$. Does the indefinite integral have another form in this limit?

Comment: Why don't we put $x+a=y?$

Comment: I tried that in Mathematica, but the indefinite integral it returns assumes that n < 0. Does this help in some way?